# Checking text against several options

Tags: c#, .net, regex, cassette

I'm very rusty on my regex and have spent about 2 hours trying to do something which should be very simple.

Basically, I want a regex expression that can check a bunch of file names (the end goal being to exclude the ones not relevant - this is for using the FileSearch class in Cassette to exclude unnecessary javascipt files).

The expression I have so far is:

```
(^.+\.+min.js$) | (^Microsoft.$) | (^.+\.+min.js$) | (^.+vsdoc.js$)
```

and the text (filename) I am trying to match is

```
jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
```

This works in Espresso, but when I actually run it against some .NET code, there is no match:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg =
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(^.+\.+min.js$) | (^Microsoft.$) | (^.+\.+min.js$) | (^.+vsdoc.js$)", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);

  if (reg.IsMatch("jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"))
    Console.WriteLine("match");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("no match");

  Console.Read();
}
```

Are there any regex legends out there who can show me the light!?

Comment: Why have you repeated `(^.+\.+min.js$)` twice in your regex? And why is there a whitespace after some `)` and before some `(`.

Comment: @Rohit Your answer is correct. That is, the whitespace (I knew it would be a silly mistake like that). And I also should have added a + after the period following the string literal 'Microsoft'.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use

```
(\.min\.js|Microsoft.|\.min\.js|vsdoc\.js)$
```

---

You regex has many faults

```
(^.+\.+min.js$) | (^Microsoft.$) | (^.+\.+min.js$) | (^.+vsdoc.js$)
 -           -   -                      
 |           |   |->space would make ^ meaningless unless you use IgnorePatternWhiteSpace option 
 |           |->instead of repeating $ in each group you can keep it outside all the groups
 |->^ is not required because you only want to check the end
```